# Need help expanding a variadic macro to a sequence of stringified names and values

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I know in C++ I can get the name of a macro parameter using the # directive, like so:

```
#define FOO(value) #value
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to convert a list of parameters into a longer list that includes stringified names as well.  Given `FOO(a, b, a+b)` I want to get `"a", a, "b", b, "a+b", a+b`.

I can do this by creating N macros for potential sequences of up to N parameters, but is there a way to write this with variadic macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `BOOST_PP_ENUM` to iterate over the variadic data and add commas between each expansion:

```
#define FOO(...)                                \
    BOOST_PP_ENUM(                              \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__),    \
        MACRO,                                  \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_TUPLE(__VA_ARGS__) \
    )

#define MACRO(z, n, data) \
    BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(n, data)), BOOST_PP_TUPLE_ELEM(n, data)

FOO(a, b, a+b) //"a", a , "b", b , "a+b", a+b
```

`ENUM` takes a count of iterations, a macro, and data to give to the macro. We pass a PP tuple containing the variadic data. The macro then accesses the element with index `n`. You can see this work [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/902c046d73815ed2).